# What is the name of invoked deity and ritual in this video?

Tags: rituals, tamil

[image: Screenshot from the video]
I saw [this video](https://x.com/moderndravidan/status/1700634674794471737?s=20) on X (Twitter), which is a practice I saw people describing as pre-brahmanical dravidian religion.

What is the name of invoked deity and ritual in this video?